# Using sorted() in Python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Syntax behind sorted(key=lambda :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966538/syntax-behind-sortedkey-lambda)

I was going through the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/howto/sorting.html) and came across this example:

```
> student_tuples = [
      ('john', 'A', 15),
      ('jane', 'B', 12),
      ('dave', 'B', 10), ]

> sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda student: student[2])  # sort by age 
[('dave', 'B', 10), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('john', 'A', 15)]
```

What I don't understand is what are lambda and student here? Can they be replaced by any other names? And what the `:` do in `student:student[2]`? It's a little ambiguous since I've never come across this before.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Semantically, this:

```
print sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda student: student[2])
```

is the same as this:

```
def sort_key(student):
    return student[2]

print sorted(student_tuples, key=sort_key)
```

`lambda` just provides an alternative syntax for function definition. The result is a function object, just like the one created by `def`. However, there are certain things that `lambda` functions can't do -- like defining new variables. They're good (depending on who you ask) for creating small one-use functions, such as this one.

Once you understand that, then all you have to know is that `key` accepts a function, calls it on every value in the sequence passed to `sorted`, and sorts the values according to the order that their corresponding `key` values would take if they were sorted themselves.

Answer (score 3):

`lambda` is a way to define a function inline, and the part before the colon `:` is the parameter to the function; in this case it's called `student`. In this example the function is simply returning the third part of the list or tuple passed to it, which is the age.