# sort two joined querysets - django

Tags: python, django

I have a join of two querysets:

```
fqs= FirstModel.objects.all()
sqs= SecondModel.objects.all()
sorted_qs = sorted(chain(fqs, sqs)) #<- need to sort here by "added" field.
```

both models have this `added` field.

```
added = models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=true)
```

but `sorted_qs` is giving me each time different order. I think, chain joins them randomly each time..

I need to sort by certain fieldname. how do i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sorted needs to know the key:

```
sorted_qs = sorted(chain(fqs, sqs), key=lambda obj: obj.added)
```

see here:
[Using sorted() in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791923/using-sorted-in-python)

Comment: then add reverse=True

Comment: @doniyor Or just use `lambda obj: -obj.added`