# How does this example of a lambda function work?

Tags: python, lambda

I’m learning about lambdas in Python, but I don’t understand what’s going on in this example.

Can anyone explain what's going on here in plain English? The example says it's “passing a small function as an argument”, but I don’t understand what that means.

```
>>> pairs = [(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four')]
>>> pairs.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[1])
>>> pairs
[(4, 'four'), (1, 'one'), (3, 'three'), (2, 'two')]
```

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8966627/1160796

Comment: this does what you asked it to do ... sorting by index 1 (which is the second element of your tuples)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're using a [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) (*or anonymous function*), to `sort` your list of tuples based on a certain `key`. `pair[1]` indicates that you are sorting with a key of the elements in the index position of 1 in each tuple (*the strings*). Sorting with strings sorts by alphabetical order, which results in the output you are seeing.

Were you to use the first element in each tuple as the sorting `key` for instance (`pair[0]`), you would then sort in increasing numerical order:

```
>>> pairs = [(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four')]
>>> pairs.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[0])
>>> pairs
[(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four')]
```