# Understanding lambda's sort function in python

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to sort the list of lists in python. I have written the following code:

```
def sort(intervals):
    if intervals == [] : return []  
    intervals.sort(key = lambda x:x.start)
    return intervals

a = [[1,3],[8,10],[15,18],[2,6]]
print(sort(a))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'start'
```

Please can someone explain lambda function for sort and some details about the above error. Thank you!!

Comment: How do you want to sort your list?

Comment: sorted list : [[1,3],[2,6],[8,10],[15,18]]

Comment: `key=operator.itemgetter(0)`

Comment: Good answers to the question have been posted below. I'd also like to note that the line `if intervals == [] : return return [] ` is unnecessary because `[].sort() == []` so the empty list will be returned even without that line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for your error message is that you are `sort`ing based on an attribute that is not for `list` (`start` is not an `attribute` of a `list')`, so quick fix is, either to use the `sort` method of `list` or use built-in method `sorted`:

1 - Using `sort` method of `list`:

```
intervals.sort(key = lambda l:l[0])
```

2 - Using built-in method `sorted`:

```
intervals = sorted(intervals, key=lambda l:l[0])
```

Reading more about sorting list in this [wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) post, very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
intervals.sort(key = lambda x:x[0])
```

`lambda` is a fast-way of making functions. For example,

```
def getFirst(x):
   return x[0]
```

is equal to:

```
getFirst = lambda x: x[0]
```

I guess you should read the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions).

**PS:** Be aware that you are making **in place** sorting. You can also use `sorted(a, key=lambda x:x[0])` which returns another copy of sorted array, if you want otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `lambda` creates an anonymous function where `x` is the parameter. `Key` is basically assigning the result from this function as the basis for the sort. A much more in depth answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966538/syntax-behind-sortedkey-lambda)

But it looks like you are looking for something like this:

```
intervals.sort(key = lambda x:x[0])
```

Where `x[0]` is obviously the first element of each list.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't actually necessary to use a lambda function to sort a list of lists. Take the following example:

```
a = [[1,3],[8,10],[15,18],[2,6],[2,5]]
print (sorted(a))
```

... this gives the output:

```
[[1, 3], [2, 5], [2, 6], [8, 10], [15, 18]]
```

... thus it not only sorts on the first element of each sub-list but uses the subsequent elements as keys if the first elements of two sublists are equal.