# Sort rows of a 2D array, based on the first column

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting

I want to sort the rows of a 2D array based on the elements of the first column, in Python 3. For example, if

```
    x = array([[ 5. ,  9. ,  2. ,  6. ],
               [ 7. , 12. ,  3.5,  8. ],
               [ 2. ,  6. ,  7. ,  9. ]])
```

then I need the sorted array to be

```
    x = array([[ 2. ,  6. ,  7. ,  9. ],
               [ 5. ,  9. ,  2. ,  6. ],
               [ 7. , 12. ,  3.5,  8. ]])
```

How can I do that? A similar question was asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31754342/sorting-a-2d-array-based-on-the-first-column), but it does not work for me.

Comment: If my answer suits you, please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[ 5. ,  9. ,  2. ,  6. ],
               [ 7. , 12. ,  3.5,  8. ],
               [ 2. ,  6. ,  7. ,  9. ]])

x[x[:, 0].argsort()]
```

```
Out[2]:
array([[ 2. ,  6. ,  7. ,  9. ],
       [ 5. ,  9. ,  2. ,  6. ],
       [ 7. , 12. ,  3.5,  8. ]])
```

Documentation : [numpy.argsort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
#using sorted    
x = ([[5.,9.,2.,6. ], [7.,12.,3.5,8.], [2.,6.,7.,9.]])
x = sorted(x, key=lambda i: i[0]) #1st col 
print(x)
```