# Python: sorting a list by "column"

Tags: python, sorting

How can I sort a list-of-lists by "column", i.e. ordering the lists by the ith element of each list?

For example:

```
a=[['abc',5],
   ['xyz',2]]

print sortByColumn(a,0)

[['abc',5],
 ['xyz',2]]

print sortByColumn(a,1)

[['xyz',2],
 ['abc',5]]
```

Comment: There is a similar question here [How to sort (list/tuple) of lists/tuples?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121979/how-to-sort-list-tuple-of-lists-tuples

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `sort` with its `key` argument equal to a [`lambda function`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966538/syntax-behind-sortedkey-lambda):

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[0])
[['abc', 5], ['xyz', 2]]

sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[1])
[['xyz', 2], ['abc', 5]]
```

Another way would be to use `key` with [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), which creates the required lambda function:

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(a, key=itemgetter(1))
[['xyz', 2], ['abc', 5]]
```