# Python : sorting a list of strings, all capitalized first

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, case

How to sort a list of strings so that the number of capitals beginning the string is the main criterion?

What I have:

```
names = ["JOE", "Kate", "WILfried", "alfred", "denis"]

print sorted(names)

>>> ['JOE', 'Kate', 'WILfried', 'alfred', 'denis']
```

What I would like:

```
>>> ['JOE', 'WILfried', 'Kate', 'alfred', 'denis']
```

**EDIT**

In other words, I would like:

- in first positions, sorted strings beginning with *n* capitals
- then, sorted strings beginning with *n-1* capitals
- " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " " *n-2* " " " " " "
- etc.

(Capitals following at least one lowercased character doesn't matter.)

Comment: What do you mean? JustinB

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966538/syntax-behind-sortedkey-lambda

Comment: Surely "Kate" should come before "WILFRIED"? If not, please explain your sorting rules more carefully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax behind sorted(key=lambda :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966538/syntax-behind-sortedkey-lambda)

Comment: Adi C: The default sorting puts 'Kate' between 'JOE' and 'WILfried, but I would like strings with more capitals at the first positions.

Comment: @taalf I've put the question on hold - you've got requirements spattered about in comments that you're not clarifying. Please take the time to [edit] your question to clarify exactly what it is you're after. Answers are descending into guessing now.

Comment: @taalf Check out my answer hope it satisfies what you wanted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following function satisfies the requirement

```
l = ['JOE', 'Kate', 'WILfried', 'alfred', 'denis']
def k(x):
  for i,j in enumerate(x):
    if j.islower():
      return (-i,x)
  return (-len(x),x)

print(sorted(l,key=k))
```

This gives following output:

```
['JOE', 'WILfried', 'Kate', 'alfred', 'denis']
```

The function k gives weight to the number of uppercases appearing at the start of the string.
EDIT: Thanks @jdeseha for edits

Comment: I'd use `not j.isupper()` (in case there are numbers or symbols) and just put the `return` after the `for` (note that your function may return `None` if, for example, the argument ends with a number. Also the cast to float doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: it just works :) thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use :

```
print(sorted(names,key = lambda x: (not x.isupper(), x)))
>>> ['JOE', 'WILFRIED', 'Kate', 'alfred', 'denis']
```

**UPDATED :**

...

Comment: It will fail for ['JOE', 'WILfried', 'Kate', 'alfred', 'denis']

Comment: Probably want this to be `lambda x: (not x.isupper(), x)` for cases where the original list doesn't happen to already be in sort order.

Comment: @JonClements thanks you're right

Comment: @taalf See my comment above is it right for that input

Comment: @RajanChauhan, i understand what you mean, but i'm not sure the goal is to count the number of capitalized letters ? i think it's allcaps first, then the others

Comment: You'r right Rajan... PRMoureu I updated the question because yes, the goal is to have something general.

Comment: But what I see is the capital letter should be given priority over alphabetical order.

Comment: @PRMoureu The thing is, if it were just counting the number of initial capital letters, `CANdy` would go before `JOE`. Maybe it is the... number of initial capital letters divided by the lenght of the string? :S

Comment: Rajan you understood exactly my problem

Comment: jdehesa, sorry I am trying to be as responsive as possible and make mistakes. Give me a minute to update the question.

Comment: Simply, in first positions: strings beginning with n capitals, then strings beginning with n-1 capitals, etc.

Comment: @taalf, and how handle capitals only in the end of the words ?

Comment: PRMoureu: the word "canDY" or "cAnDy" can be treated as the word "candy"

Comment: @taalf can you edit these comments into your original question - your question, your example and answers have now become completely different...what with all these new rules/logic in comments under this answer

Comment: @taalf Updated !

Comment: @RajanChauhan Thanks for pointing out that case

Comment: @PRMoureu I'm afraid it's not correct D: If you replace the `CANDy` with `cANDy` in your input list, it will place it before `Kate`.

Comment: @jdehesa yeah i just forget i need to break the loop...

Comment: @PRMoureu so now your only sort key is based on the total number of capital letters (*anywhere* in the string)... So... try... an input of `['Candy', 'donkEY']`... I'm not sure the output is what's expected...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a (somewhat ugly) solution:

```
names = ['JOE', 'Kate', 'WILfried', 'alfred', 'denis']
k = lambda s: ([-i for i, u in enumerate(map(str.isupper, s)) if not u] or [-len(s)],
               s.lower())
print sorted(names, key=k)
>>> ['JOE', 'WILfried', 'Kate', 'denis', 'alfred']
```

Maybe you want to put that `lambda` as a proper function.

Comment: Fixed now (hopefully!)

Comment: Hmm, just realizing, the order this yields is: first every all-caps string, then order by number of initial number of caps (until no initial caps). Not sure if that is alright or instead it should be ordered by initial number of caps only.

Comment: Do somehow what I need. Very appreciate the effort. Will adapt it in case I meet a situation not handled but this is a very good start. Thanks!

Comment: Ah... the Rajan's answer respects the number of caps... So I will validate this one. Nevertheless, thank you for your help :)

Comment: @taalf Yep, I've made a small edit to emulate the same behavior... It's about the same as Rajan's answer, although his is probably clearer (and, in theory, slightly more efficient, since it stops at the first non-uppercase of every string).