# Explanation needed for sorted(dictionary) using lambda as key

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I'm quite new with python and I've question to ask about lambda. I had dictionary which was needed to print sorted as by it's values.

```
def print_in_accordance_of_values(english_spanish):
    for value, key in sorted(english_spanish.items(), key = lambda value: value[1]):
        print(key, value)

def main():
    english_spanish = {"hi": "hola", "thanks": "gracias", "yes": "si", "no": "no"}
    print_in_accordance_of_values(english_spanish)

main()
```

What actually happens in this part of the code:

```
for value, key in sorted(english_spanish.items(), key = lambda value: value[1]):
```

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax behind sorted(key=lambda :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966538/syntax-behind-sortedkey-lambda)

Comment: BTW, it's more efficient to _not_ use a `lambda` function. Instead, you should use `itemgetter` from the standard `operator` module for this. Eg, `key=operator.itemgetter(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's concentrate on the part `sorted(english_spanish.items(), key = lambda value: value[1])`, because that's what your question is about.
The generator (think of it as a list in this case) `english_spanish.items()` yields the pairs:

```
('hi', 'hola')
('thanks', 'gracias')
```

and so on.
To get them sorted, the `sorted` function needs to know how to. The key word `lambda` creates a little anonymous function which gets the pairs (as `value`) and yields the second entry of each pair. This is what `sorted` takes as a key to sort upon.