# TypeError when sorting a dictionary

Tags: python, sorting

```
 property_dict = {
         "u" : ("unit", "Unit"),
         "h": ("hsn", "HSN"), 
         "n": ("name", "Name"), 
         "t": ("gst_rate", "GST Rate"), 
         "a": ("abbr_name", "Abbreviation"), 
         "pg": ("product_group", "Group"), 
         "rq": ("reorder_qty", "Reorder Qty"), 
         "s": ("stock", "Stock"), 
         "pln": ("price_list_name", "Price List Name"), 
         "plv": ("price_list_value", "Price List Value")
         }
 property_dict_keyorder = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(["u", "h", "t", "a", "pg", "rq", "s", "pln", "plv"])}


 property_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(property_dict.items(), key=lambda    i: property_dict_keyorder.get(i[0])))
```

Error:

> ```
> property_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(property_dict.items(), key=lambda i: >     property_dict_keyorder.get(i[0]))) TypeError:
> unorderable types: int() < NoneType()
> ```

I am trying to sort the dictioanry with keyorder. 
I printed the `property_dict_keyorder`

> ({'a': 3, 'pln': 7, 'u': 0, 'rq': 5, 'h': 1, 'pg': 4, 's': 6, 't': 2,
>   'plv': 8})

and checked the order is as desired but on sorting I get the above error.

I read
[Syntax behind sorted(key=lambda :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966538/syntax-behind-sortedkey-lambda)
But I am still unable to understand what is going wrong?

Comment: It doesn't look like `"n"` is in your ordering.

Comment: Why are you not just making an OrderedDict from a list of key-value pairs in the first place, anyway?

Comment: `property_dict_keyorder.get(i[0])` is returning `None`, because `i[0]` isn't present in the dictionary.

Comment: Python 3 (unlike Python 2 will not tolerate comparison between int and None.  the  docs explain why you are getting None in the first place "Docstring: D.get(k[,d]) -> D[k] if k in D, else d.  d defaults to None.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method"

Comment: yes, missed "n". Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A dictionary in Python is a collection of unordered values accessed by
>   key rather than by index. The keys have to be hashable: integers,
>   floating point numbers, strings, tuples, and frozensets are hashable,
>   while lists, dictionaries, and sets other than frozensets are not.

You have two option :

either use `[collections.OrderedDict][1]`

or use this method tuple format as key , value pair :

Alert : please check you have not all the keys in keys_order list like 'n'

```
order=["u", "h", "t", "a", "pg", "rq", "s", "pln", "plv"]
property_dict = {
         "u" : ("unit", "Unit"),
         "h": ("hsn", "HSN"),
         "n": ("name", "Name"),
         "t": ("gst_rate", "GST Rate"),
         "a": ("abbr_name", "Abbreviation"),
         "pg": ("product_group", "Group"),
         "rq": ("reorder_qty", "Reorder Qty"),
         "s": ("stock", "Stock"),
         "pln": ("price_list_name", "Price List Name"),
         "plv": ("price_list_value", "Price List Value")
         }

key_value=[0]*len(property_dict.keys())
tuple_format=[(i,j) for i,j in property_dict.items()]
for value in tuple_format:
    if value[0] in order:
        key_value[order.index(value[0])]=value

print(key_value)
```

output:

```
[('u', ('unit', 'Unit')), ('h', ('hsn', 'HSN')), ('t', ('gst_rate', 'GST Rate')), ('a', ('abbr_name', 'Abbreviation')), ('pg', ('product_group', 'Group')), ('rq', ('reorder_qty', 'Reorder Qty')), ('s', ('stock', 'Stock')), ('pln', ('price_list_name', 'Price List Name')), ('plv', ('price_list_value', 'Price List Value')), 0]
```

output: