# Sorting a list of string based on digit

Tags: python

I have a list of string

```
line = ["set_param(find_system('Fccroot_to_ICD','RegExp','on','FindAll','on','Name','B10_Stat_TRXA_FCC'),'port', '1218');",
"set_param(find_system('Fccroot_to_ICD','RegExp','on','FindAll','on','Name','Az_INS3_RawValidity'),'port', '1438');"]
```

I am trying to sort is based on last digit 1438 and 1218
sorting numerically ..'1438' should be treated as number

below lines doesn't give me expected result

```
line = sorted(line)

["set_param(find_system('Fccroot_to_ICD','RegExp','on','FindAll','on','Name','Az_INS3_RawValidity'),'port', '1438');",
 "set_param(find_system('Fccroot_to_ICD','RegExp','on','FindAll','on','Name','B10_Stat_TRXA_FCC'),'port', '1218');"]
```

Comment: the last digit in both of your examples is `8`, are you trying to sort them alphabetically or numerically?

Comment: I think he meant by the last number, comparing 1438 to 1218

Comment: @vash_the_stampede - Comparing how? alphabetically or numerically? What should come first with 107 and 11?

Comment: @Sayse well his response has them 1408 first and is wrong so if you have 107 and 11, I would say he wants 11 first 107 second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the sub-string from the last comma onwards and then extract the digits from that string.

```
sorted(line, key=lambda s: int(''.join(c for c in s.split(',')[-1] if c.isdigit())))
```

---

giving

```
["set_param(find_system('Fccroot_to_ICD','RegExp','on','FindAll','on','Name','B10_Stat_TRXA_FCC'),'port', '1218');", 
"set_param(find_system('Fccroot_to_ICD','RegExp','on','FindAll','on','Name','Az_INS3_RawValidity'),'port', '1438');"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex to find the last occurrence of digits surrounded by single quotes in the key argument of `sorted`:

```
import re

sorted(line,key=lambda x: int(re.findall("'(\d+)'", x)[-1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data stays in that format:

```
>>> sorted(line, key=lambda x: int(x.split()[-1][1:-3]))
["set_param(find_system('Fccroot_to_ICD','RegExp','on','FindAll','on','Name','B10_Stat_TRXA_FCC'),'port', '1218');",
 "set_param(find_system('Fccroot_to_ICD','RegExp','on','FindAll','on','Name','Az_INS3_RawValidity'),'port', '1438');"]
```

I takes each line, splits it, and then takes the last item (e.g. `"'1218');"` for the first line).  It then strips the first character (`'`) and the last three (`');`) via slice notation.  Finally, it converts this text value to an integer and uses it as a key for sorting.

A regex solution is more general.

```
sorted(line, key=lambda x: int(re.findall(r'(\d+)', x.split()[-1])[0]))
```

This will fail if the last item in the split does not contain any digits.

Comment: This is what I was going for as well, but we would have to assume it will always be 4 digits correct?

Comment: Oh you are right, it will always have 3 characters at the end, I was thinking your index was based off the width of the numbers but yes it will always be that index

Comment: `new = sorted(line, key=lambda x: int((x.split()[-1]).split("'")[1]))` I went similar route forgetting the index will always be `[1:-3]`

Answer (score 0):

Use python regex (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) to extract the integer value at the end of the strings, then you can create a function which takes your string as an argument, and returns the integer.

Finally, used a lambda to the key argument to the sorted method to pass in the function. Python will used your function as the key to sort with. (like this: [Syntax behind sorted(key=lambda: ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966538/syntax-behind-sortedkey-lambda) )

Answer (score 0):

Not as good as @Alexander response, same result but extra step

```
new = sorted(line, key=lambda x: int((x.split()[-1]).split("'")[1]))
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 list.py
>
> ["set_param(find_system('Fccroot_to_ICD','RegExp','on','FindAll','on','Name'
> ,'B10_Stat_TRXA_FCC'),'port', '1218');", 
> "set_param(find_system('Fccroot_to_ICD','RegExp','on','FindAll','on','Name',
> 'Az_INS3_RawValidity'),'port', '1438');"]
> ```