# What is lambda? How can you explain this sorting

Tags: python, lambda

Please be gentle I'm still learning Python. I've an example where

> pairs = [(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four')]
>
> pairs.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[1])

The result is

> [(4, 'four'), (1, 'one'), (3, 'three'), (2, 'two')]

Can you please help explain why this is the sequence?

Comment: A `lambda` is an anonymous function: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions

Comment: `lambda` is the same as an unnamed function, i.e. `def f(pair): return pair[1]`.  You will do well to brush up on the vast documentations and tutorials on beginner basics of Python before venturing further...

Comment: Give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966538/syntax-behind-sortedkey-lambda) post a look

Comment: *All* functions are anonymous; the `def` statement simply binds the function to a name after it has been defined. A `lambda` expression is an expression (rather than a statement) that can create a function as long as the body of the function is itself a single expression.

Comment: Adding to what was already said : you are establishing a criteria on how to sort. The lambda function returns the second element for each tuple. Therefore, you are sorting by the second element of your tuples.

Comment: There is an incredible pletora of materials on Python Lambda functions, so I suppose that here the issue is not really 'what a lambda is'.
Maybe the keyword arguments in the `sort` function may be misleading: it does not contain the key _attribute_ upon which sorting, but the _function_ that extracts the key that will be used for sorting. That function is thus invoked on each element of the list.

Comment: Aha! The sorting is alphabetical from the second element! Sorry to bother you nerds, like I said please be gentle to anyone who wants to learn.

Answer (score 0):

A lambda is simply a short way of declaring a simple function. That code could just as easily have been written:

```
pairs = [(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four')]

def key_func(pair):
    return pair[1]

pairs.sort(key=key_func)
```

In this case, the lambda function is telling `sort` how it should turn a value in the array (in this case, a tuple which doesn't have an obvious sorting order) into a value that it knows how to sort (a string).