# How to sort list of strings alphabetically with upper and lower values?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
v = ['zack', 'timor', 'Topher']
v.sort()
print(v)
```

> ['Topher', 'timor', 'zack']

What I want to get is:

> ['timor','Topher', 'zack']

which is the correct alphabetic order.

Basically it should ignore the difference between lower and upper letters.
I can't just do lower() because `['timor','topher', 'zack']` is not the desired output.

in simple words I want it to compare with this rule:  `a=A, b=B, ...`
How can I do that?

Comment: you can do a more complicated map function where essentially you remember which words got changed, sort them and change them back. You can do this with a fairly naively in python using a 2d array and sorting both arrays. I can write an answer if you would like

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, so the sort function allows you to specify a key with which to compare elements;

`v.sort(key=str.lower)`

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Answer (score 4):

You can specify a key function for sort. This would do it for this data:

```
v = ['zack', 'timor', 'Topher', 'Quark', "quark"]
v.sort( key= lambda x: x.lower())
print(v)

v = ['zack', 'timor', 'Topher', 'Quark', "quark"]
v.sort( key= lambda x: (x.lower(), x[0].isupper()))  # this will sort lower before upper
print(v)

['Quark', 'quark', 'timor', 'Topher', 'zack']  # keep original order
['quark', 'Quark', 'timor', 'Topher', 'zack']  # always lower before upper, only 1st char
```

But `v.sort( key= lambda x: x.lower())` will stable sort - meaning it sorts by lowercasing and keeps the occurence order of the original list.

See

- [How to sort a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139/how-to-sort-a-list-of-strings) for
- [Syntax behind sorted(key=lambda: ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966538/syntax-behind-sortedkey-lambda)

Answer (score 1):

Add a key to your sorting, like:

```
def case_insensitive_sort(a):
    return a.lower()

v = ['zack', 'timor', 'Topher']
v.sort(key=case_insensitive_sort)
print(v)
```